# Mongodb - How to return an empty array when the condition for its nested object array field is False?

Tags: mongodb

I'm struggling to query documents now.
I have documents like this:

```
# reviews

{
    _id: 1,
    category_id: 1,
    comments: [
        {
            _id: 1,
            context: "abc",
            is_deleted: false
        }
    ]
}
```

and I've tried to query like this:

```
db.reviews.aggregate(
    [
        {"$match": {"category_id": 1}},
        {
         "$unwind": {"path": "$comments", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": True}
        },
        {"$match": {"comments.is_deleted": false}},
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "category_id": {"$first": "$category_id"},
                "comments": {"$push": "$comments"},
                }
            },
    ]
)
```

it worked fine but the one thing is wrong.
when all elements of `comments` don't match the condition, it doesn't return parent too. but what I exactly want is to return [] when all elements of array don't match.

I'll add an example for your understanding:

what I expected:

```
[{
    _id: 1,
    category_id: 1,
    comments: []
}]
```

what I actually got:

```
[]
```

I've tried `$filter` but It excludes the parent object if any of elements of array are not met.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "category_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "comments": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$comments",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.is_deleted",
              false
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z-KGrhLj15H)